# Toggle a class for each element within a node list?

Tags: javascript, nodelist

Been working on a simple to-do-list using javascript linked below.

https://codepen.io/Marty_Marty_Maro/pen/NWaBjKP

For the life of me, I cannot understand why the checked class only applies to every second list item generated. I've played around with different variations including trying using forEach() but I don't know how to iterate and select every single list item individually and toggle a class for each element and I feel out of ideas as to why this issue is occurring. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const inputText = document.getElementById("myInput");
const closeButton = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

// Code to add new task through enter key
inputText.addEventListener('keydown', addNewItem);

function addNewItem(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    let inputTextElement = inputText.value;
    let newItem = document.createElement("li");
    newItem.innerHTML = `
    ${inputTextElement}
    <div class="check">
      ✓
    </div>
    <div class="close">
      ✕
    </div>
  `
    document.getElementById("unorderedList").append(newItem);
    inputText.value = "";
    addCheckedClass();
    removeItem();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// Code to add new task through add button
document.querySelector(".add-element").addEventListener('click', clickNewItem);

function clickNewItem(e) {
  let inputTextElement = inputText.value;
  let newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.innerHTML = `
    ${inputTextElement}
    <div class="check">
      ✓
    </div>
    <div class="close">
      ✕
    </div>`

  document.getElementById("unorderedList").append(newItem);
  inputText.value = "";
  removeItem();
}

// Code to remove item with remove button;
function removeItem() {
  for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".close").length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".close")[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.target.parentElement.remove();
    })
  }
}

// Code to add checked class to indivdual items
function addCheckedClass() {
  for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".check").length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".check")[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      event.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('checked');
    })
  }
}



// Code to remove all items;
let button = document.querySelector(".clearall");
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let testy = button.parentElement.parentElement;
  console.log(testy)
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul,
li,
h2,
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.to-do-list-container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: hotpink;
  padding: 40px 0 20px 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.newtask-element {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.input-element {
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#myInput {
  border: none;
  width: 900px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 5px;
}

.add-element {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.to-do-next {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.remove-button {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 12px 24px 12px 24px;
}

.close:hover {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 12px 24px 12px 24px;
}

.check:hover {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.checked {
  background: #ababab;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.clearallitems {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.clearall {
  padding: 20px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="to-do-list-container">
  <div class="title-container">
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="newtask-element">
    <div class="input-element">
      <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Add new to do item...e.g. go to the gym">
    </div>
    <div class="add-element">
      +
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="to-do-list-items">
    <ul id="unorderedList"></ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearallitems">
    <button class="clearall">Clear All Items</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Running your code and reading your question I cannot understand at all what your specific problem is.

Comment: What makes absolutely no sense is that you're adding event listeners to **all items** every time **one**  new item gets added.

Comment: you probably forgot to call `addCheckedClass();` from the function `clickNewItem()` after line `inputText.value = "";`. It really works on function `addNewItem()`

Comment: Remember to mark the answer that solved your problem "correct".

Answer (score 0):

Not working with `innerHTML` makes your life so much easier because it allow you to add event listeners at the time of creating the elements.

I have rewritten your code and simplified and shortened it by alot:

```js
const inputText = document.getElementById("myInput");
const closeButton = document.querySelectorAll(".close");
const list = document.getElementById("unorderedList");

// Code to add new task through enter key
inputText.addEventListener('keydown', addNewItem);

function addNewItem(e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    const newItem = document.createElement("li");

    const inputTextElement = document.createTextNode(inputText.value);
    
    const check = document.createElement("div");
    check.textContent = "✓";
    check.className = "check";
    check.onclick = markDone;

    const close = document.createElement("div");
    close.textContent = "✕";
    close.className = "close";
    close.onclick = removeItem;
    
    newItem.append(inputTextElement, check, close);

    list.append(newItem);
    inputText.value = "";
  }
}

document.querySelector(".add-element").addEventListener('click', addNewItem);

// Code to remove item with remove button;
function removeItem(event) {
  event.target.closest("li").remove();
}

// Code to add checked class to indivdual items
function markDone(event) {
  event.target.closest("li").classList.toggle("checked");
}

// Code to remove all items;
document.querySelector(".clearall").addEventListener('click', () => list.innerHTML = "")
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul,
li,
h2,
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.to-do-list-container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: hotpink;
  padding: 40px 0 20px 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.newtask-element {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.input-element {
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

#myInput {
  border: none;
  width: 900px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 5px;
}

.add-element {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.to-do-next {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.remove-button {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 12px 24px 12px 24px;
}

.close:hover {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 12px 24px 12px 24px;
}

.check:hover {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.checked {
  background: #ababab;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.clearallitems {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.clearall {
  padding: 20px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="to-do-list-container">
  <div class="title-container">
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="newtask-element">
    <div class="input-element">
      <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Add new to do item...e.g. go to the gym">
    </div>
    <div class="add-element">
      +
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="to-do-list-items">
    <ul id="unorderedList"></ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearallitems">
    <button type="button" class="clearall">Clear All Items</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Don't think I would've got that on my own. Do you recommend working with InnerHTML at all then?

Comment: It has its purposes, especially if the amount of elements that need to be created grows. I'm almost never using it though.